# Another set of parentheses after a function call [C++]

Tags: c++, iife

I've met this as an example in a book (rewritten in a more generic form), however, the problem which I'm curious about is not explained.
*It works, I've tested it.*

**Q.:**

- What does this another set of parentheses after the function call mean?
- How is this pattern/syntaxis called to read more about it?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename FUNCTION>
auto compose(FUNCTION&& f)
{
    return [=](auto x){ return f(x);}; // where does the x come from?
}

int main() {
    std:: cout << compose([](int const n) { return n*2; })(4); // How is 4 captured? What is (4) here?
}
```

Comment: It's a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), an unnamed function object

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes Pythoner know this just too good … cool name btw XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just some funny code to illustrate a point I guess.

```
[](int const n) { return n*2; }
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This code defines an anonymous function (lambda). It is transformed by the compiler to a construct similar to this one:

```cpp
struct {
  operator()(int const n) { return n*2; }
};
```

Now `compose()` takes this struct and packages it in another likewise struct that has a constructor and stores the struct above in a member variable.

You end up with a call `operator()(4)` on an anonymous struct.

Comment: However, `compose` is not a lambda. So, I guess this syntax is allowed for any function? I've never met it before.

Comment: The point is that `compose` returns a function, for which the `(4)` is the argument list.

Comment: @MykolaTetiuk `compose` returns a lambda, which gets immediately called on return

Comment: @MykolaTetiuk `compose` however does return a lambda, thus the result of `compose` is callable. You're calling that result with the parameter `4`, that is where `x` is coming from.

Comment: Thanks (!) Now I get it: compose returns a lambda and for lambdas this addition works as an *initializer*.

Comment: or to restate that, what returned is basically: lambda(4)